# Explicit conversion of out-of-bounds value in Ada

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, ada

Suppose I have declared some types

`type ABC_TYPE is range 0 .. 7;
 subtype AB_SUBTYPE is ABC_TYPE range 0 .. 3;
 type DE_TYPE is range 1 .. 4;`

what is the expected behavior of:

`abc : ABC_TYPE := 7;
 ab : AB_SUBTYPE := AB_SUBTYPE(abc);
 de : DE_TYPE := DE_TYPE(abc);`

when compiling without range checks?

Comment: Why program in ada at all? I mean, I'm not trying to be rude, just curious about what ada can offer and not to choose another language.

Comment: @imaluengo : Early diagnostics. This code ought not to survive as long as the first compile without range checks. It's often taught that bugs are easier and cheaper to eliminate the earlier they are caught; how widely accepted this idea is in practice, I'm not so sure.

Comment: And indeed as the violations can be detected at compile time, there is no runtime penalty to the range checks; the compiler issues a warning and can simply place an unconditional jump to the "Constraint Error" exception handler if it wants.

Comment: Even a C compiler could detect comparable compile-time range violations. Hell, an assembler could. It's more interesting with run time values of some kind.

Comment: @imaluengo I learned Ada in college and was impressed. It was a much safer language than any other I have seen. (E.g. the ability to define sub types of numbers which cannot be assigned to each other without explicit conversion, even if they have the same range. Think meters/feet or liters/gallons. That eliminates whole classes of errors, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter.) I think Ada is still used where correctness is paramount, e.g. traffic lights, air craft.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not even sure how you would express a 3-bit integer in C so the compiler could check this. Did I miss something in K&R? However: I agree the runtime case is more interesting, but it's remarkable how many of those the compiler can eliminate too.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Well, "comparable" was hinting at int -> byte assignments etc.

Comment: @PeterSchneider and BrianDrummond Thx for the lesson! Was just curious about ada, never worked with it, and all I've heard about it is "Its a dead language".

Comment: @imaluengo Ada is far from dead, It is quite prominent in its intended markets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob said, the result is not defined by the language.  The most likely behavior is that the compiler will generate code that treats the values as integers with a certain "natural" range, and will simply copy the integers around as long as they fit into the range.

In your example:

```
type ABC_TYPE is range 0 .. 7;
subtype AB_SUBTYPE is ABC_TYPE range 0 .. 3;
type DE_TYPE is range 1 .. 4;

abc : ABC_TYPE := 7;
ab : AB_SUBTYPE := AB_SUBTYPE(abc);
de : DE_TYPE := DE_TYPE(abc);
```

On the most commonly used processors, the compiler will store the variables as a 1-, 2-, or 4-byte integer.  The range of a 1-byte integer will be either 0..255 or -128..127--for this case, it doesn't really matter.  So what will happen is that 7 will be stored in the 1-, 2-, or 4-byte integer allocated for `de`.  Then, when the program accesses `de`, it most likely will just read that integer and work with it.  I'd expect `DE_TYPE'Image(de)` to work fine, because there is likely to be some low-level function that converts an "integer" to an image, that accepts any 32-bit (or 64-bit) integer as a parameter.  **Please note that I am not recommending you rely on this behavior.**  This is just what I think is most likely to happen given what I know about how compilers generate code.  Note also that although `ab` could be stored as a 2-bit integer, the compiler is unlikely to do so (except in a packed record or packed array) because it's not a natural integer size that processors can deal with.

In this case, though:

```
type ABC_TYPE is range 0 .. 10000;
subtype ABC_SUBTYPE is ABC_TYPE range 0 .. 100;

abc : ABC_TYPE := 1234;
ab : AB_SUBTYPE := AB_SUBTYPE(abc);
```

Now, it's possible that if range checking is suppressed, a compiler could truncate `abc` to a byte before assigning it to `ab`.  This would happen by chopping off the upper byte, leaving 210, which means `abc` would have the value 210 or -46 depending on whether the byte is treated as signed.  (It's still out of range for an `AB_SUBTYPE`, but since range checking is suppressed, that won't cause an exception.)  Different compilers may have different behavior in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Without range checks it isn't Ada, so the result is undefined.  You can try it out with different compilers, and see what they do, but it is (technically at least) a lucky coincidence if some of them do the same.

Comment: Since `pragma Suppress` is part of the language, I think it _is_ Ada! (however ill-advised)

Comment: @SimonWright Agreed on compiling without range checks being ill-advised, though when in production, it produces a much more optimal binary. Also, thank you for the example you provided.

Comment: @notAlex you would have to do some performance measurements with and w/o checks to be sure to say "in a much more optimal binary" (no, 10% is not much more optimal unless it is inside main inner loop and you are tight for CPU time budget... where you can turn them off only there)

Comment: @SimonWright - Although `pragma Suppress` is a part of the language, there is still 11.5(26): "If a given check has been suppressed, and the corresponding error situation occurs, the execution of the program is erroneous."

Answer (score 3):

As written, your code contains constraint violations that can easily be detected at compile time. `pragma Suppress (All_Checks)` allows the compiler to suppress *runtime* checks ([ARM 11.5(2)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-11-5.html#p2)), but GNAT takes the opportunity to say

```
notalex.adb:11:23: warning: value not in range of type "AB_Subtype" defined at line 7
notalex.adb:11:23: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
notalex.adb:12:20: warning: value not in range of type "DE_Type" defined at line 8
notalex.adb:12:20: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
```

and then

```
$ ./notalex 

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : notalex.adb:11 range check failed
```

However, if you make it slightly more difficult for the check to be made at compile time, as here,

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Notalex is

   pragma Suppress (All_Checks);

   type ABC_Type is range 0 .. 7;
   subtype AB_Subtype is ABC_Type range 0 .. 3;
   type DE_Type is range 1 .. 4;

   abc : ABC_Type;
   ab : AB_Subtype;
   de : DE_Type;

   procedure Check (Value : ABC_Type) is
   begin
      abc := Value;
      ab := AB_Subtype (abc);
      de := DE_Type (abc);
   end Check;

begin
   Check (7);
   Put_Line ("abc: " & ABC_Type'Image (abc));
   Put_Line ("ab: " & AB_Subtype'Image (ab));
   Put_Line ("de: " & DE_Type'Image (de));
end Notalex;
```

the runtime check is suppressed. With GNAT (on Mac OS X), the output is

```
$ ./notalex 
abc:  7
ab:  7
de:  7
```

about which there are two things to say: first, your program is now executing outside its design envelope, and the consequences may be disastrous; and second, it’s fortunate that GNAT’s implementation of `ABC_Type’Image` and friends didn’t also fail when faced with out-of-range inputs.